# How to fill the PDAnnotationLink rectangle with a color?

Tags: c#, hyperlink, pdfbox

I have implemented functionality to add a hyperlink to a pdf using Pdfbox library.Now I want to implement functionality to fill the link rectangle with color.I tried using the setColor function, but it has no effect.Below is the code that I am tried:

```
PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
COSArray colorValues = new COSArray();
colorValues.add(COSInteger.get(0));
colorValues.add(COSInteger.get(0));
colorValues.add(COSInteger.get(0));
PDColor color = new PDColor(colorValues.toFloatArray(), PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
txtLink.setColor(color);
```

Comment: It would have an effect on the border if there was one (paint it black), which depends on your border style setting. Filling with a color doesn't seem to be possible out of the box. You'd have to create your own appearance stream. I once managed to do this and it displays nicely except in Adobe Reader. Seems that Adobe Reader insists on doing its own appearance even if there is one. What worked instead (with Adobe Reader) was to create a highlight annotation at the same place where the link annotation is. Very weird.

Comment: Did you use PDAnnotationTextMarkup for the highlight?

Comment: Adobe Reader did. But yes, that would be a PDAnnotationTextMarkup. You can try it yourself with Adobe Reader, just use the "yellow marker" symbol. Save and then have a look at it with PDFDebugger.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I did not understand the 'Adobe reader did' .Also, I used PDAnnotationSquareCircle, and it works fine.

Comment: I interactively used Adobe Reader.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr you were able to create a page link annotation via PDAnnotationTextMarkup?

Comment: @chitgoks that was five years ago... from what I see there, I did the appearance of a PDAnnotationLink myself and it worked with PDFBox but not with Adobe Reader.

Comment: yes. long time. i wondered if things might have worked out later on. im satisfied with this even if there's no background possible (even acrobat reader pro, doesnt have this feature). but i wonder if text selection highlight supports page links, or these kinds are only limited to a rectangle area provided?